# Incrementing variable in a if statement

Tags: java, counter, increment

Here is a snippet of code (an `else` clause):

```
else { // for operators
            int count = 1;
            if (sub.compareTo("+") == 0){ //if + operator
                double d1=stack.pop();
                double d2=stack.pop();
                answer=d1+d2;
               //first two items on stack added
                stack.put(answer); // put ans on stack
               System.out.println(count+ ") "+d1+ " + " +d2 + " = " +answer); // display ans
               count++;
            }
            if (sub.compareTo("-") == 0){ //if - operator
                double d1=stack.pop(); //pop first two items on stack
                double d2=stack.pop();
                answer =d2-d1; //subtract the items
                stack.put(answer);//put ans on stack
                System.out.println(count+ ") "+d2+ " - " +d1 + " = " +answer);///display answer
                count++;
            }
}
```

This code tries to evaluate basic mathematical operations using a `stack`. Examples are:

1. 2 + 2 = 4
2. 4 + 4  = 8

I want to use the `count` variable to display the number but it stays at 1. Do you know why?

Comment: so how do i fix the error?

Comment: Is `count` *really* not changing from 1? Did you use debugger? Isn't it just incremented to 2, vanished and initialized to 1 again?

Comment: how do i store the incremented number?

Comment: By writing code to store it, compile and run. Please post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Make your **count** global variable and declare it outside the function to store the values properly, What you are doing is limiting the scope of count that's why he's giving you same answer every time

```
int count=1;  // make sure you count is outside your function 
else{ // for operators

            if(sub.compareTo("+")==0){ //if + operator
                double d1=stack.pop();
                double d2=stack.pop();
                answer=d1+d2;
               //first two items on stack added
                stack.put(answer); // put ans on stack
               System.out.println(count+ ") "+d1+ " + " +d2 + " = " +answer); // display ans
               count++;
            }
            if(sub.compareTo("-")==0){ //if - operator
                double d1=stack.pop(); //pop first two items on stack
                double d2=stack.pop();
                answer =d2-d1; //subtract the items
                stack.put(answer);//put ans on stack
                System.out.println(count+ ") "+d2+ " - " +d1 + " = " +answer);///display answer
                count++;
            }
```

Comment: Genarally using global variables is not considered as good.

Comment: so put it just outside the function, declare a local variable can limit you to specific function body